# What are the highest FIDS yields possible for each planet type?

Tags: endless-space

For the large majority of the game, the planets you're dealt are the planets you get. But as you approach Endless Space's endgame, terraforming options start to open up, and suddenly the formerly simple task of resource optimization gets much harder.

Sure, a basic 0/1/1/5 Arctic is obviously worse than a basic 2/1/2/5 Tundra, but the Arctic planet gets different bonuses from improvements and the like - +0/0/0/5 with a Global Tech Park compared to the Tundra's +0/0/0/3.

While resources and anomalies obviously factor into this, terraforming the planet won't affect them, so they're moot for this purpose. What are the highest yields from exploits and system improvements alone?

Comment: What you're also not factoring in is that the Tundra (and later, the terran/ocean) planet has room for more population.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Endless Space groups the varying planet types into different groups. By default, only Class 1 Planets will be colonizable, and you unlock the ability to colonize planets in the higher tiers as you move down the tech tree.

By contrast, terraforming unlocks in the *reverse* order, so, as mentioned, you probably won't have favorable terraforming projects available until late game. Generally though, you have to move up in class if you want a net positive in FIDS - otherwise you're either losing them, or swapping Science and Industry, etc.

You can only have one exploit per planet, so I've listed them separately, as some planet types get increased benefit from multiple exploit types.

### Category 1 Planets (11 Base FIDS)

#### Terran

Base: 3/2/4/2

Tier 3 Exploits: 3/0/1/0

Food:

- +2 Epigenetic Crop Seeding

Dust:

- +1 Xenotourism Agencies

Total: 5/2/5/2 + Exploit

#### Ocean

Base: 3/2/2/4

Tier 3 Exploits: 2/0/0/2

Food:

- +2 Epigenetic Crop Seeding

Dust:

- +1 Xenotourism Agencies

Total: 5/2/3/4 + Exploit

#### Jungle

Base: 3/4/2/2

Tier 3 Exploits: 2/2/0/0

Food:

- +2 Epigenetic Crop Seeding

Dust:

- +1 Xenotourism Agencies

Total: 5/4/3/2 + Exploit

### Category 2 Planets (10 Base Fids / -5 Approval)

#### Arid

Base: 2/2/5/1

Tier 3 Exploits: 1/0/3/0

Food:

- +1 Sustainable Farms
- +1 Epigenetic Crop Seeding

Industry:

- +1 Heavy Isotope Refining

Dust:

- +1 Xenotourism Agencies

Science:

- +1 Optics Research Lab

Total: 4/3/6/2 + Exploit

#### Tundra

Base: 2/1/2/5

Tier 3 Exploits: 1/2/0/0

Food:

- +1 Sustainable Farms
- +1 Epigenetic Crop Seeding

Industry:

- +1 Heavy Isotope Refining
- +1 Interplanetary Transport Network

Dust:

- +1 Xenotourism Agencies

Total: 4/3/3/5 + Exploit

### Category 3 Planets (7 Base FIDS / -10 Approval)

#### Arctic

Base: 1/0/1/5

Tier 3 Exploits: 0/0/0/2

Food:

- +1 Sustainable Farms
- +1 Epigenetic Crop Seeding

Industry:

- +1 Heavy Isotope Refining

Science:

- +1 Non-Baryonic Collider

Total: 3/1/1/6 + Exploit

#### Desert

Base: 1/5/0/1

Tier 3 Exploits: 0/0/2/0

Food:

- +1 Sustainable Farms
- +1 Epigenetic Crop Seeding

Industry:

- +1 Heavy Isotope Refining
- +1 Interplanetary Transport Network

Science:

- +1 Optics Research Lab

Total: 3/7/0/2 + Exploit

### Category 4 Planets (5 Base FIDS / -15 Approval)

#### Barren

Base: 0/1/4/0

Tier 3 Exploits: 0/0/0/3

Food:

- +2 Wasteless Supply Chain

Industry:
Dust:
Science:

- +2 Non-Baryonic Collider
- +2 Optics Research Lab

Total: 2/1/1/4 + Exploit

#### Lava

Base: 0/4/1/0

Tier 3 Exploits: 0/3/0/0

Food:

- +2 Wasteless Supply Chain

Industry:

- +2 Interplanetary Transport Network

Science:

- +2 Optics Research Lab

Total: 2/6/1/2 + Exploit

### Category 5 Planets (12 Base FIDS / -20 Approval / Cannot Terraform)

#### Gas Methane

Base: 0/10/1/1

Tier 3 Exploits: 0/1/0/0

Food:

- +1 Wasteless Supply Chain

Science:

- +1 Optics Research Lab

Total: 1/10/1/2 + Exploit

#### Gas Helium

Base: 0/1/1/10

Tier 3 Exploits: 0/0/0/1

Food:

- +1 Wasteless Supply Chain

Total: 1/1/1/10

#### Gas Hydrogen

Base: 0/1/10/1

Tier 3 Exploits: 0/0/1/0

Food:

- +1 Wasteless Supply Chain

Science:

- +1 Optics Research Lab

Total: 1/1/10/2

#### Asteroid Belt

Base: 0/4/4/4

Tier 3 Exploits: 0/0/0/0

Food:

- +1 Wasteless Supply Chain

Industry:

- +1 Interplanetary Transport Network

Total: 1/5/4/4 + Exploit

Terraform priorities will come in a bit.

Comment: Note that the higher tier planets have higher population caps, so the math is even more in favor of terran/ocean/jungle planets.

Answer (score 1):

I still suggest against terraforming any higher than Tier 2 cause by the time the 6400 ind pay for themselfes the game most likely is over. Better churn out ships instead of taking the last step